# Is it possible to include all javascripts files from one folder in JSF?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.0, and am looking for a means to include all the javascripts from a given folder on a page, i.e. do something like

```
<h:outputScript library="javascript" name="*.js" target="head" />
```

Is this kind of thing even possible? Should I write a custom component using java code to achieve this?

Thanks for your help,
Sébastien Tromp

Comment: I don't have the answer, but it's an interesting question really. In case this isn't possible with the standard facilities it would make a great feature request for JSF 2.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice idea. This is not supported by the JSF API, but it's in theory possible with a custom script renderer. I played somewhat around it and it's indeed possible. Just create a `MultiScriptRenderer` which `extends ScriptRenderer` and override [`encodeEnd()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/render/Renderer.html#encodeEnd%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIComponent%29) to check if the `name` attribute contains the `*` wildcard and then handle accordingly by scanning for files matching this pattern in the resources folder.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.ScriptRenderer;

public class MultiScriptRenderer extends ScriptRenderer {

    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> attributes = component.getAttributes();
        String name = (String) attributes.get("name");
        if (name.contains("*")) {
            String pattern = name.replace(".", "\\.").replace("*", ".*");
            String library = (String) attributes.get("library");
            File root = new File(context.getExternalContext().getRealPath("/resources/" + (library != null ? library : "")));
            for (File file : root.listFiles()) {
                if (file.getName().matches(pattern)) {
                    attributes.put("name", file.getName());
                    super.encodeEnd(context, component);
                }
            }
            attributes.put("name", name); // Put original name back. You never know.
        } else {
            super.encodeEnd(context, component);
        }
    }
}
```

Register it in `faces-config.xml` as follows *(Sorry, [`@FacesRenderer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/render/FacesRenderer.html) annotation isn't going to work until it's fixed in JSF 2.2 for this specific corner case, see also [JSF issue 1748](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1748))*:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.resource.Script</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.MultiScriptRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Works fine on Mojarra 2.0.3 here. You can use patterns like `*.js` and `prefix*.js`. The particular code example is only tight coupled to a specific JSF implementation to save code boilerplate. It also requires that the WAR is expanded on deploy, otherwise browsing the directory by `File#listFiles()` won't be possible (which thus excludes certain (older) servletcontainer versions/configurations). For other JSF implementations you'll have to extend its `ScriptRenderer` instead, or write a whole new one if you want to be implementation independent (which should be pretty simple though, just look at standard `ScriptRenderer` source if you stucks).

Comment: Thanks for this. In the meantime, I have found something to work around the need to include several javascript files, but I'm definitely keeping this at hand for later.

Comment: You (auto-)compressed/minified all loose JS files into a single JS file? That's indeed also often done to save the amount of HTTP requests.

Comment: Reference the OmniFaces solution here

Answer (score 3):

I didn't test this, but if wildcards are not accepted, you could fetch the filelist via java code in a backing bean, and insert them into head using `c:forEach` or `ui:repeat` like:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.files}" var="file">
    <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="#{file}" target="head" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Note that you cannot give absolute paths to `h:outputScript` but you must extract the prefix from them (the part the preceeds the JSF resources path).