# Load many css in JSF

Tags: css, jsf

I come from Dot Net experience. I already used MVC to develop Web Application.
Now I'm approaching to Java and JSF for Dynamic Web project.
I'm asking if in Java there is an equivalent component to System.Web.Optimization.BundleCollection. I would like to load many css file by path, for example

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").IncludeDirectory(
            "~/Content/_css", "*.css", true));
```

What can I do in JSF? I have no idea.

Comment: Sure, many options... Did you try a search engine?https://www.google.com/search?q=css+optimization+bundle+jsf+-.net+site:stackoverflow.com Many (most) are not jsf related but basic java web development... Pick the one that suites you most.

Comment: Why would you need to load many files? All my CSS comes from JSF component libraries and I have 1 CSS file to do overrides.

Comment: @JasperdeVries: OP is asking it sort of the wrong way around... Title should have bean "How to load 1 css instead of many"... That is wat the .Not feature does

Comment: I have divided styles into several part, for maintenance and porting purposes.
I looked for solutions in Google and I found something about using "ui:repeat" and "h:outputStylesheet". In this manner I need to implement class to store in a List the file's names. I'm wondering if there are better ways.

Comment: What you googled for is totally unrelated (the 'hits' in the link I posted do not contain this do they?) Use https://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CombinedResourceHandler (down at the moment) or a maven resource combiner (plain not jsf related css minifyer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to include all javascripts files from one folder in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482443/is-it-possible-to-include-all-javascripts-files-from-one-folder-in-jsf)